# Array out of bounds error with quick sorting

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

I'm not sure why, but this keeps giving me an array out of bounds error when I compile it. Assuming the array is initialized correctly to have 10 index positions and I pass to the method 0 and numbers.length - 1, what am I doing wrong?

```
public void sort(int low, int high)
{
    int temp1 = low;
    int temp2 = high;
    int pivot = numbers[low + (high - low)/2];

    while(temp1 <= temp2)
    {
        while(numbers[temp1] < pivot)
        {
            temp1++;
        }
        while(numbers[temp2] > pivot)
        {
            temp2--;
        }
        if(temp1 <= temp2)
        {
            swap(temp1, temp2);
            temp1++;
            temp2--;
        }
    }
    if(low < temp1)
    {
        sort(low, temp2);
    }
    if(temp2 < high)
    {
        sort(temp2, high);
    }
}

public void swap(int temp1, int temp2)
{
    int temp = numbers[temp1];
    numbers[temp1] = numbers[temp2];
    numbers[temp2] = temp;
}
```

Comment: It says the out of bounds happens at:

while(numbers[temp1] < pivot)

Comment: surely you get the error when you _run_ it, not when you _compile_ it?

Comment: Yes sorry, when I run it.

Comment: I think you need to provide a SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Comment: @PythonNoob       Put your code snippet in the question please! Also, Did you check the debugger to find out where exactly it breaks? Chances are that you are using low and high parameters which you didn't consider whilst writing the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
if(low < temp1)
{
    sort(low, temp2);
}
```

should be

```
if(low < temp2)
{
    sort(low, temp2);
}
```

And this:

```
if(temp2 < high)
{
    sort(temp2, high);
}
```

Should be:

```
if(temp1 < high)
{
    sort(temp1, high);
}
```

This doesn't explain the error you are seeing, but you are sorting too much of the sub-arrays. You don't need to include the pivot value in the recursive sort; it's already in the right place.

Also:

```
while(temp1 <= temp2)
```

Could be:

```
while(temp1 < temp2)
```

... since there's no point trying to swap an element with itself. However this could leave the loop with temp1 == temp2, in which case you might want to adjust the later recursive calls; so perhaps leaving the condition as `temp1 <= temp2` is a better bet.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing temp1 vs temp2 while you should be comparing numbers[temp1] and numbers[temp2]. That comparison (if(temp1 <= temp2)) and the swapping after that may lead to temp1 exceeding the array size.

Comment: No. It is correct to compare temp1 and temp2. The idea is that temp1 is the index of the next number higher than the pivot value and temp2 the index of the next lower number than the pivot value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume davmac's answer is right!
But I would like to point out why you got out of bound exception!

Assume `sort` is called with `sort(0, 1)`, then, if `numbers[1] > numbers[0]`, we will have `temp1 = 1` and `temp2 = -1` after the loop `while(temp1 <= temp2)`. Now you check:

```
if(low < temp1)
    {
        sort(low, temp2);
    }
```

Since `low = 0` is less than `temp1 = 1`, `sort` will be called with `sort(0, -1)` which will give out of bound exception. :)